# renv::restore() failed to retrieve older package version

Tags: r, renv

I am using `renv` for a project where I need to use an old version of `mongolite` (version 1.0). I can install this version with `remotes::install_version("mongolite", "1.0")`. However, `renv` fails to install this package upon `renv::restore()`. I tried to insert explicite sources into the `lock`-file like this:

```
"mongolite": {
      "Package": "mongolite",
      "Version": "1.0.0",
      "Source": "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/mongolite/mongolite_1.0.tar.gz"
    }
```

(I also tried `https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite/archive/refs/tags/v1.0.tar.gz`). It just didn't work (`Error: failed to retrieve package 'mongolite'` ). I also tried to set `Sys.setenv(RENV_DOWNLOAD_FILE_METHOD = getOption("download.file.method"))` like suggested in the FAQ, but this didn't help either.

Is there anything else I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you posted the entire output you saw on the failure of `renv::restore()`. The only thing that stands out to me is that the version is 1.0, not 1.0.0, so that could be why `renv` is failing to find the package (assuming you're manually modifying the lockfile).

Comment: Thanks, indeed the problem was the numbering. I tried it on a new, clean project and it works with 1.0, but not with 1.0.0 (yes, I modified the lockfile manually).